# Is there a way to pass the OnSelect value of a dropdown inside a component, to App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown

I have a searchbar component that contains my dropdown in question. I am wanting to get the selections from the OnSelect value of the dropdown component and pass them to App.js to be used in the handler below.

App.js handler

```
 const [value, setValue] = useState("");
const dropdownHandler = (e) => {
  console.log(e);
  setValue(e);
};
```

Normally I would be able to set the onSelect method, to dropdownHandler directly, if the component was inside of App.js. However, I am unsure of how to do this when the components are modular.

Searchbar.js

```
 <DropdownButton className="dropdown"
      title="Search Filters"
      id="dropdown-menu"
      // onSelect={dropdownHandler}
    >
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="ddFirstName">First Name</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="ddLastName">Last Name</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="ddTitle">Title</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="ddPhoneNumber">Phone Number</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item eventKey="ddLocation">Location</Dropdown.Item>
    </DropdownButton>
```

App.js calling the searchbar component.

```
  <div className="centered-container">
      <Searchbar
          searchQuery={searchQuery}
          setSearchQuery={setSearchQuery}
        />
      </div>
```

What is the best way to pass the value from this dropdown back to App.js, so I can use the handler function I have written?

Comment: Can you share the `Dropdown` component as well please? But usually We can pass the state and setState thru props... so the state would be declared in the App.js and then passed to the Searchbar thru props and then used in the dropdown component... if this becomes a lot of props going down (prop drilling) then the best way is to use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: The dropdown component is shown. Its a part of the searchbar object. I probably phrased that poorly. It is everything in the dropdown button tags. So I need to access the contents of <dropdownButton> inside of the searchBar object from App.js

Comment: You can pass it down as props to `<SearchBar selectedOption={state} onSelected={handler} searchQuery={searchQuery} setSearchQuery={setSearchQuery} />` and pass it to the Dropdown on the `onSelect` that is commented and add a `value={state}` (if that's the implementation for reading the dropdown value)... Then App will be controlling the Dropdown component thru the SearchBar component. In React props can only go down, from the parent to the child and you can pass state and functions as props. As the child uses the setState, the parent component will trigger the re-rendering of the children